# Cервисы для удаленной разработке на macOS

Tags: xcode, macos

Есть несколько идей для своего стартапа. Одна из них реализуется с применением дополнительной реальности. Насколько я знаю, сейчас есть нормально работающее только для iOS/iPadOS. Для разработки для этих систем, купить нормальный iMac/Macbook Pro пока возможности нет. Хотел бы узнать от коллег, про опыт использования каких-либо сервисов, которые предоставляют возможность разработки на macOS и в XCode. Их тарифные планы, сервис, возможность ставить свой собственный софт и самое главное про конфиденциальность, могут ли местные админы зайти туда, полазить по файлам и всё в таком духе?

Comment: «могут ли местные админы зайти туда» — всегда могут, пока они контролируют своё собственное железо.